# In $S_5$, we have $aba^{-1}=b^2$, $b=(12345)$, find $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

In $S_5$, we have $aba^{-1}=b^2, b=(12345)$, find $a$.

I have tried different ways to substitute/rearrange, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that for any cycle $(abc...)$ and permutation $\sigma$, $\sigma(abc...)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a)\sigma(b)...)$. In your case, $b^2=(13524)$, so $a(1)=1$, $a(2)=3$, $a(3)=5$, $a(4)=2$, $a(5)=4$, and putting this all together in cycle notation: $a=(2354)$.

Comment: There's a small error in your answer. Your $a$ as written is not a permutation.

Comment: Since $(13524) = (41352) = (24135) = (52413) = (35241)$ there are four other possibilities for $a$.

Comment: @MattSamuel It...is? Can you clarify? Are you talking about the fact that I could write it as $(1)(2354)$? Because normally in cycle notation you leave off the elements that are fixed.

Comment: @ZoeH A good point to make. $a$ is by no means unique.

Comment: $a$ is not a bijection. I'm sure it's a typo.

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah, good eye. Thanks for pointing that out.